# Spring RestTemplate readtimeout property not working properly - strange issue

Tags: java, spring, sockets, weblogic, resttemplate

I want to consume 2 services and want to have different timeouts. So, I have overridden Spring's `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and using it from my `HttpDaoImpl`.

Now everything works in one environment but exact same EAR doesn't work in other environment, and only difference in both the environments is that the service URL I am connecting is load balanced URL in one and non-LB in other. Issue is in load balanced service URL.

Problem is that everytime `httpReadTimeout` is taking effect or being used but not `XYZHttpReadTimeout`, even though I am conditionally setting the time out.

It is extremely strange issue because everything is working in one env. and not in other. My guess for probable root cause till now is the load balanced URL but still I am not able to see any technical reason on why load balanced URL could be issue because my machine will open a socket and close it after read timeout.

I have placed loggers in `CustomClientHttpRequestFactory` and verified that correct values are being used but in the end somehow read timeout is not working as expected.

**CustomClientHttpRequestFactory.java**:

```
public class CustomClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory{

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CustomClientHttpRequestFactory.class);

    @Value("${httpRequest.readTimeoutInMilliseconds}")
    private Integer httpRequestTimeout;

    @Value("${httpRequest.connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds}")
    private Integer httpReadTimeout;

    @Value("${XYZ.httpRequest.readTimeoutInMilliseconds}")
    private Integer XYZHttpRequestTimeout;

    @Value("${XYZ.httpRequest.connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds}")
    private Integer XYZHttpReadTimeout;

    @Value("${sgw.XYZHttp.service.url}")
    private String XYZSystemUrl;


    /**
     * Overriding the default and setting a separate read timeout and HTTP connection timeout values for XYZ transactions.
     * 
     * @param uri
     */
    public void setTimeoutProperties(URI uri){
        boolean isXYZTransaction = isXYZTransaction(uri);
        Integer connectionTimeout = isXYZTransaction ? XYZHttpRequestTimeout : httpRequestTimeout;
        Integer readTimeout = isXYZTransaction ? XYZHttpReadTimeout : httpReadTimeout;
        logger.info("Setting " + connectionTimeout + " : " + readTimeout);
        this.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        this.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
    }

    private boolean isXYZTransaction(URI uri){
        try {
            URI XYZUrl = new URI(XYZSystemUrl);
            logger.info("################################### XYZ Debug");
            logger.info("XYZHttpRequestTimeout = " + XYZHttpRequestTimeout);
            logger.info("XYZHttpReadTimeout = " + XYZHttpReadTimeout);
            return XYZUrl.equals(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HttpDaoImpl**:

```
    CustomClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = (CustomClientHttpRequestFactory) myAppUtils.getApplicationContext().getBean("httpRequestFactory");
    httpRequestFactory.setTimeoutProperties(lUri);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory);
    responseString = restTemplate.postForObject(lUri, requestString, String.class);
```

**XML config**:

```
<bean id="httpRequestFactory" class="com.abc.xyz.customComponents.CustomClientHttpRequestFactory" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name = "supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <value>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, found the issue and got it working.

**Root cause:**
Spring's `RestTemplate` by default uses `org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and it has issues in case of multi-threaded environment. This will pose issue when `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` is used in multi-threaded environment and more than one set of timeout values are used, based on some rule of yours (in our case different timeouts based on URLs or service I am consuming).

A [blog](http://vincentdevillers.blogspot.ca/2013/02/configure-best-spring-resttemplate.html) highlighting the same.

That's makes sense because another difference in 2 environments I have talked in my question was one environment (where everything was fine) had always one user which means only one thread and the other environment (where I had issues) had many concurrent users which means multiple threads.

**Solution:**
Use `org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory`, which is another implementation of `org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory` available in Spring version 3.0.6 and works well in multi-threaded environment.

If Spring version is 3.0+ then use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

Comment: This is happening to me even though i'm using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. Happening on one environment but not on the other. I have two restTemplates, each configured with their own timeout, 1min and the other 3min. What I'm seeing is that the timeout is 1min for everything.

Comment: I didn't try `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` but I know for that it works with `org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory`

Comment: Nevermind, I found the cause for my problem. It was actually an apache httpd server on the frontend that had a Timeout setting of 1 minute. Thanks @hagrawal .

Comment: @hagrawal thanks for the useful information. Just one question, can I have one RestTemplate and change the timeout per request like you described, and will it be thread safe? Because currently I have multiple RestTemplates, like one RestTemplate with readTimeout of 1000ms, and another one with 3000ms.. so each time they require a new timeOut value I create a new RestTemplate and I think my current design is bad. See my last posted question. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: @prettyvoid Sorry for late reply. I think you can use singleton RestTemplate and create separate "CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory" per request and set the request specific timeout on it.